# Broken Laptop Screen, HDMi isn't working anymore

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display

I recently dropped my Windows 10 x64 laptop and it caused the screen to go all coloured with lines, and I pretty much can't see any relevant information on the screen anymore. I was able to connect to a TV via HDMi fine but I foolish thought it was a good idea to update my Nvidia graphics driver. After doing so, the TV will recognize that there is something connected via HDMi but it will not show any signal. I'm thinking the graphics driver update messed things up, maybe the refresh rate from my research I'm not overly sure.

I've probably tried every combination of connecting the HDMi cable to the laptop, tv, starting from powered off or starting from powered on. In addition, I've tried all of the Windows + P (duplicate, extend, 2nd screen only) display options to no success either.

I'm just looking for advice as what to do, seeing as I can't see my screen I can't really rollback the graphics driver. Is there any way I can get the display on my smartphone or something? I've been at this for hours trying to figure it out so any insight is appreciated.

I cannot take it to the repair shop yet, I'm just asking if there's anything else I might be able to do in the mean time.

Thanks

Comment: Take it to the repair shop.

Comment: The problem might be as simple as a bad connection. Without any screen you can't even rollback Windows to a previous system restore point. If you know how, open the laptop and check all connectors. Otherwise, a repair-shop is the only solution.

Comment: If you have VGA or DVI output, then use a monitor to roll back the drivers (or better, to restore them from your last backup). If it does *not* have other video out, you can find USB to DVI or VGA adapters for ~US$50, if it's worth the cost.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same peoblem. I used the narrator tool to get the application called TeamViewer. Then I used another laptop to remotely control the broken laptop and update driver. Now it works fine with HDMI.

Comment: This is actually a pretty clever solution. You could even use a mobile device or tablet if you didn't have a 2nd computer.